# load testing with vs2008, how do I get stats from the system under test?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, load-testing, web-testing

When running a webtest or load test on a website using VS2008 Test edition how can I get the CPU etc of the webserver? I am sure I am being very slow here but I cannot work out how to set it up!

I can remote onto the webserver if that helps any.

As a rider question, can I import perfmon stats back into an already-run test?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding the counter sets to your load test. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404676.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have tried shoe-horning data into a previously run test in the database. Visual Studio 2008 did not load up my results.

I have not seen anything to indicate that it is/is not possible.